# Flutter - appbar button border/background

Tags: flutter, dart, button, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

How can I make my app bar buttons (notification button and, I don't know, menu?) look like that?
I mean, how can I copy this `border` or **background**. Maybe I should use something else than appear?

[image]

Now I am using this:

````
class _CustomAppBarState extends State<CustomAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.menu,
          color: Color(0xff736f71),
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          color: Color(0xff736f71),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Just use `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,` inside Scaffold

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making app bar you can add something like this into your body

```
Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white24,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white30),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 20),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: const [
            Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I meant. Im talking about this border around buttons, that rounded square.